# Monday as first day , full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Full calendar haves an option called **firstDay** where you can chose the first day , I want to chose Monday and I set `firstDay:1` but it doesn't work on timelineMonth of fullcalendar-scheduler, it only works on basicAgenda,basicMonth.... etc, but in timeline it doesn't , why is this so?

Comment: I don't see any differences between fullcalendar and scheduler (documentationwise), perhaps they have separate documentation that is only avalable if you purchased it? Try to work with [locale](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/)

Comment: how to work with locale? please explain

Comment: You have specific file for each language and its specific timezone (Full list can be [found here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/tree/master/locale)) so you include the relevant js file right after the scheduler library, and you init the plugin using the `locale` property as [described here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/) - I don't know if it will solve the problem, but I hope so (Never used scheduler, only fullcalendar)

Comment: First day doesn't choose the first day to be displayed, it chooses the first day of _each week_. If you're in a view where that makes sense (e.g. a week view with 7 days across the top, or a month layout with each week on a separate row) then it's clear that it will put that day on the left-hand-side of the view for any given week. How you'd expect that to apply to a scrolling timeline view is not clear. If you have a "month" view, then it strikes me as somewhat inevitable that it will start on the first day of that month, no matter what day of the week it happens to be.

Comment: That's only my take on it though, if you want a full explanation of the reasoning you might be better to ask the developer directly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ADyson that in the month view you would expect it to start on the first day of the month rather than a Monday.

If however you want to display Monday as the first day then you might be able to use a custom view.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: moment().startOf("month").startOf("isoweek"), // Show closest monday
  defaultView: "timelineFourWeeks",
  views: {
    timelineFourWeeks: {
      type: "timeline",
      duration: moment.duration(28, "d"),
      buttonText: "fourWeeks"
    }
  }
});
```

This will create a custom timeline view with a duration of 28 days, it then finds the closet Monday to the start of the month. So loading it up today (December 29th) it will set the first Monday as November 27th.

Comment: @andrew did this help at all?